# Custom font warning in browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fonts, webfonts

I'm using custom font in web application, chrome showing following warning message in console.

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: resource url/fontname.woff
```

I've added following lines in `.htaccess`,

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
```

it have not solved the issue, so I've included following line in `.htaccess` with above lines,

```
AddType application/octet-stream         .woff
```

though still warning message appears in the browser.

Comment: Sure that your `.htaccess` style file is interpreted _at all_? Apart from that: any reason why you do not put such general configuration statements into the real main http server configuration? That would be much faster and more reliable.

Comment: @arkascha: I've even tired by keeping above mentioned lines in httpd.conf file, but warning messages are still appearing.

Comment: Then there is little sense in _trying around_. IT is not a guessing game. You have to look for the cause of the problem, not move things around at random ;-) When you enter those statements in the main server configuration _and restarted the http server afterwards_... any messages in the http servers error log file? Either this, or you have to grant that configuration for certain locations by the `AllowOverride` option further up.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks for scolding, I'll trying to improve myself further.

Comment: It was meant in a friendly, motivating way. Sorry if you got that wrong.

Comment: @arkascha: No errors have logged when restarted/reloaded the apache2 in log files. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

`AddType application/font-woff            .woff`

Is the correct type. Your problem is most likely that you can't use AddType in .htaccess because it is disabled in httpd.conf. You need:

AllowOverride FileInfo

-or-

AllowOverride All

Specified in a `<Directory>` context in httpd.conf; but then if you can edit the main configuration you should really add the type there as a global (or upgrade apache to get a more up-to-date MIME list).

PS. Whatever else you try, delete `AddType application/octet-stream         .woff` first. This declaration is plain **wrong** and may override the correct rule.

Comment: `AllowOverride All` statement is already exist in virtual host file and I'm sure that `.htaccess` is all time interpreted. Even I've tried keeping above line in `.httpd.confi` file, though problem persists.

Comment: AllowOverride is not valid in a VirtualHost context, only in a Directory context.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, httpd.config file is empty by default. Normally I use application configuration changes in `/etc/apache2/site-available/` files, Sorry if anything is wrong. Thanks for support.